# solving laplace in 3d using finite differences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-differences

I have created a function `laplace3d()` which accepts a 3D array describing the boundary conditions and -Inf at the places of unknown. It then calculates these unknown using finite difference method. Now the problem is that I can have any sort of 3D figure which is described in term of say matrix X. X here is n*3 matrix which store (x,y,z) of n vertices which if connected forms the 3D figure. I wanna extract a 3D matrix similar to U4c as shown in the figure from this matrix X of n*3 dimensions. I can just pass this U4c to my `laplace3d()` to get an answer. Any idea how I can create that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: As I said in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/407932/solving-laplaces-equation-using-finite-differences/408950  The matrix for finite differences generated in 3D is not very different from 2D, it is not an $n \times n \times n$ tensor, you have to enumerate your vertices differently.

Comment: yeah i figured that out, but its the input matrix that I am worried about. lapace3d() works fine if you give it the right matrix. I am worried about creating U4c matrix from a n*3 matrix decribing the coordinates of the vertices